# Can I run my own processes within Next JS runtime?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, backend

So I'm migrating from a React/Express eco-system to Next.JS and I have a problem.

In my current build, my server is more than simply an Express server that serves an API.

I also run several "microservices" within that Node application - mostly stuff related to collecting data from elsewhere to update my databases, modifying data, as well as some other processes etc.

With my current setup this is easy because I have an "entry point" for my whole application, the "server.js" (or app.js/index.js, whatever convention you follow). So upon starting my application I run this file (e.g. node server.js) and everything simply happens from there. the file contains all of my Express server config/routes, and any other processes I wish to put in there and it all runs happily in one place.

With Next, I don't see how I can achieve the same thing because I have to run the next build/run/start command and it will simply compile and do it's thing.

This is kind of a shame for me as I do not want to have to separate my microservices from my main server logic and it somewhat kills the idea of using Next JS for me.

Is there some way I can configure it to migrate to using the built in Next api directory to get all of the benefits from the framework etc. while also being able to run my other Node processes from the same place?

Comment: You can use a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), which provides more customisation of the server that runs the Next.js app (instead of using the built-in server).

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility of using custom server, but that takes away some of the advantages and reasons I want to use Next.JS in the first place